# How to use DISTINCT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY in spring-data-jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**Beware**: this question has been falsely marked as duplicate. Anyways I found a solution that I will add to my question below, as answers cannot be posted anymore on "duplicate" questions.

---

I want to transform the following `sql` query into a `JPA` query using `querydsl` and spring-data-jpa:

```
SELECT DISTINCT age FROM `my_table`
  WHERE firstname = 'john' AND lastname = 'doe'
  GROUP BY age
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Currently I have the following, which just selects all entries by first+lastname:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity> {

}
```

Usage:

```
@Autowired
private MyRepository dao;

//select * from my_table where firstname = ? and lastname = ?
BooleanExpression query = p.firstname.eq(firstname).and(p.lastname.eq(lastname));
dao.findAll(query);

//TODO how to add group, order and limit?
```

But I now want to group by `age` field and select the age that occurs the most. But how can I add `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY COUNT` and `LIMIT` statements in the querydsl?

---

**Solution**: it's not possible directly using `CrudRepository`, but still easy by using `com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery` as follows:

```
QPersonEntity p = QPersonEntity.person; //the querydsl definition

int age = new JPAQuery(em)
    .select(p.age)
    .from(p)
    .where(p.firstname.eq(firstname).and(p.lastname.eq(lastname)))
    .groupBy(p.age)
    .orderBy(p.age.count().desc())
    .limit(1)
    .fetchOne();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if returning count and other information is an option unless you do some special projection class to cover that, maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352967/spring-jpa-using-multiple-projection-on-same-query-interface/43373337#43373337 will help

Comment: I think `querydsl` supports keywords like `group` and `distinct`, but I don't know how to hook this into the `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`.

Comment: apart from that you can do findDistinctByFirstNameAndLastNameOrderByFirstName(String first, String last, Pageable limit)

Comment: I know, but I have to "group by" and "order by count". How to achieve this using the functional approach?

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson this is **not** about `projection`. It's about how to use `DISTINCT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY` with spring-data-jpa! That's a totally different subject!

Comment: Not a dup I guess. Apart from what the OP says, this question refers to how to implement it with querydsl, whereas in the linked question it's done using standard spring data repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method in your `@Repository` in order to expose a method that performs the required operation with a native query. In fact, as report in the Spring Data JPA reference docs:

> The @Query annotation allows executing native queries by setting the
>   nativeQuery flag to true.

You can add this code snippet in your `@Repository`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT age "+
               "FROM my_table "+
               "WHERE firstname = :firstname AND lastname = :lastname " +
               "GROUP BY age " +
               "ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC " +
               "LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
int retrieveAgeByFirstNameAndLastName(@Param("firstname") String firstname,
                                      @Param("lastname") String lastname);
```

Comment: if it's not possible with HQL/JPA, then this might probably fit best.