# Spring JPA/Hibernate: use multiple projections on same query interface

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

this is a similar question of: [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352967/spring-jpa-using-multiple-projection-on-same-query-interface)

I tried to use the same solution, but I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: from near line 1, column 9 [select from com.app.company.domain.organization.Organization as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.deletedAt is null]
```

Look at the `select` statement: there is not any field requested!

Any idea?

Query in the Repository:

```
<T extends JPAProjection > List<T> findAllByDeletedAtIsNull(Class<? extends JPAProjection> projection);
```

Next, blank interface `JPAProjection`, and `OrgId` projection interface used to retrieve only `id` and `name`:

```
public interface JPAProjection {}

public interface OrgId extends JPAProjection {

    @Value("#{target.id}")
    Long getId();   

    @Value("#{target.name}")
    String getName();

}
```

And then, the call to the query:

```
return organizationRepository.findAllByDeletedAtIsNull(OrgId.class);
```

Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a single query method for several projections - all you need is [Dynamic projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic):

```
interface MyEntityRepo extends Repository<MyEntity, Long> {
  <T> T findById(Long id, Class<T> type);
}
```

Then you can use this method with projections and main entity as well:

```
MyEntity entity = findById(1L, MyEntity.class);
MyProjection entityProjection = findById(1L, MyProjection.class);
```